# Using OracleDB for a game inventory system - how easily find the first empty column?

Tags: sql, oracle

Having a game that allows players to pick up up to 60 items, the storage table looks like this:

```
Player_ID    Slot_1  Slot_2 ....Slot_60
```

When users picks a new item up, it should be automatically places in the lowest empty column (also if the items are it slots 1,3,4,5 the newly picked item should be placed into the slot 
number 2.

But how to select a column like this?

Answer (score 6):

You don't; you're completely correct it's a horrible query to do it the way you're suggesting.  Normalise your table so it looks like this:

```
PLAYER_ID, SLOT_ID, ITEM_ID.
```

The first empty slot is then

```
select min(slot_id)
  from storage
 where item_id is null
```